# Проверочное слово

Tags: проверочные-слова

Какое проверочное слово к слову "колёс", нужно проверить О.

Comment: @shkololo22, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Это словарное слово, пишется по традиции, но когда-то было слово "коло" - круг, от которого оно и произошло. Сейчас его нет, устарело.

Answer (score 3):

Двуколка (двухколёсная повозка).

Comment: Действительно, я как-то не сообразила, забыла об этом историзме.